# Select2 dropdown issue with iphone

Tags: ios, css, iphone, jquery-select2

I am using select2 dropdown in my web-application.

```
$("#dropdownId").val("value").trigger("change");
```

Above statement works fine when application opens in other browsers. it works even when i set device as iphone in crome's developer's tool. but when i actually opens web-application in IPhone it shows dropdown values as blank.

can anyone help me to solve this issue ?

One more question is all disabled fields are showing very light grey colored in iphone even i have put inline css color as black but still it is not getting effect of it. Please help how these can be solved.

Thanks

Comment: Do you have a mac at hand? You can use OSX safari to debug directly on your iPhone

Comment: okay. i will try using OSX safari browser to debug. but can you please help me how can i resolve this issue.

Comment: Please check fiddle code : http://jsfiddle.net/fyhsz9ra/776/

Comment: Cannot reproduce. Please give clear instructions on how to reproduce, together with your OS version.